# Laravel svg file to inline auto conversion

Tags: laravel, svg, sass

I use SVG files as `background-image` in my Laravel project's SASS files:

```
.icon-phone {
   background-image: url("../img/phone-icon.svg");
}
```

Is there a way how to convert those SVG files to inline SVG in CSS postprocess in `webpack.mix.js`?

```
.icon-phone {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='14' height='20' viewBox='0 0 14 2...");
}
```

I use totally clear Laravel project's `webpack.mix.js`. I hope a npm module exists for this so that I don't have to convert those SVG files manually (I have a lot of them). I need to use inline SVG because I have a lot of small files so a lot of HTTP requests would slow my application and because of "blinking" :hover effects (when :hover backgrounds are not loaded yet).

Comment: After a lot of Googling I found `postcss` plugin: https://github.com/TrySound/postcss-inline-svg which should work but haven't managed to use it successfully in Laravel. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a NPM-package for this. But to be honest wouldn't inlining all of your SVG-files increase your CSS-file bundle size?

Alternative:
https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

Comment: I was also considering it but I also have some SVG files for backgrounds not only for icons. But I'm open to other solutions how to cope with SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

The PostCSS plugin [postcss-inline-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-inline-svg) can do this for you.

Install the package:

```
npm install postcss-inline-svg --save-dev
```

Next, add PostCSS compilation to your `webpack.mix.js` file. You can add this as a global PostCSS option so it will apply to any CSS/SCSS/Less/Etc. file:

```js
// webpack.mix.js

mix.options({
  postCss: [
    require('postcss-inline-svg'),
  ]
})
```

Or use another method in the [Laravel Mix docs for PostCSS preprocessing](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/main/postcss).

Finally in your CSS file, use `svg-load()` to inline the SVG file.

```css
.arrow-up {
  background: svg-load('../img/arrow-up.svg');
}
```

**Note:** The path used in svg-load() is relative to the CSS file, not the server's web root.

For example, given this directory structure:

```
├── dist
│   └── assets
└── src
    ├── css
    │   └── styles.css
    └── img
        └── arrow-up.svg
```

Source files in `/src` are compiled to the `/dist` directory. Use an image path relative to `/src/css/styles.css`, in this case `svg-load('../img/arrow-up.svg')`, **not** where they are compiled to (`/dist/assets/`).

### Bonus: Optimize SVGs with SVGO

You can optimize SVGs at build time with the the [postcss-svgo plugin](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/tree/master/packages/postcss-svgo).

```js
// webpack.mix.js

mix.options({
  postCss: [
    require('postcss-inline-svg'),
    require('postcss-svgo'),
  ]
})
```